# Not loading an image from sd everytime (use WeakReference?)

Tags: android, bitmap, weak-references

I have this list of people and each person has an avatar. There's a default avatar for everyone and later you can change it (the app saves the resized and circle-cropped image to the sd).

Here's my approach:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_list_item"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/avatar_descp"
        android:src="@drawable/defavatar" >
    </ImageView>
```

This is part of the item that forms the list. `defavatar`is the default avatar I already talked about. Then:

```
String m = person.getAvatar();
    if(!m.equals(""))
    {
        loadBitmap("file://"+m, avatar);
    }
```

`getAvatar()`gets the path of the avatar of the db. If not null:

```
public void loadBitmap(String resId, ImageView imageView)
{
    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
    task.execute(resId);
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView)
    {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getContext(), Uri.parse(params[0]), 320, 320);
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null)
        {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null)
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is copied mostly from the official Android Dev Guides.

My problem is this: **Everytime** the image is loaded, again and again (and also I see first the default avatar and some ms later the new avatar instead, and this is not very nice).

I'm guessing that I can use the WeakReference (which is a cache of the image, right?) that holds in the memory until a memory leak. Am I right? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `WeakReference`. Use an [`LruCache`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) instead. Android's garbage collector is very aggressive and weak references to memory-intensive images would be cleared by the garbage collector very quickly. From Google:

> In the past, a popular memory cache implementation was a SoftReference
>   or WeakReference bitmap cache, however this is not recommended.
>   Starting from Android 2.3 (API Level 9) the garbage collector is more
>   aggressive with collecting soft/weak references which makes them
>   fairly ineffective.

For help on using `LruCache`, see this link: [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).

Also, as @Sainath suggested, use a third-party image loading library instead. There is a lot to consider when handling image loading in Android, so it's best to use a library that already takes all those factors into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Ya this is good to see from android developer site, but you should use a third party library; image loading is very costly operation which will depend on many factors

I had used Picasso library in many applications, which is very good at performance as well as memory consumption.

You can find it from http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: But the problem is not loading the images themselves, is to use the cache. The loading is done pretty fast I think.

Comment: Bro hope that your images url are may be wrong is the on case, else u encode it the second option, still if your are not able to see you use this library from http://picasa.google.co.in/